# Starting Activity From Within Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am learning and beginning to understand all about android and activity life cycles but I came across something today that confuses me.

Assume I load my MainActivity and inside the onCreate method I have some code that loads another activity.

Now what happens in a scenario where I have code in the onStart, onPause and onResume methods of my MainActivity but I am calling another activity from within the onCreate method?

Does the execution of those methods in my MainActivity get aborted or does it run anyway but on a different thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Activity lifecycle

Your current `activity` will be paused if you open up a new `activity`. This means only code in `onPause` will run. If the new `activity` closes and you return to the previous `activity` his `onResume` will be called.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me :)